# blob.cpp: Check failed: count_ == proto.data_size() (1 vs. 0)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, c++, runtime-error, caffe

I was trying to run a sample Caffe code from a [git repo](https://github.com/Pratik08/Vis-DSS). I installed Caffe on my `Ubuntu 18.04` (with `apt-get install libcaffe-cpu-dev`), and compiled this repo code and `DeepVideoSummExample` executable was actually generated successfully.

But when running, this executable asks for `googlenet_places205` model files as well as `hybridCNN` mean file, which I downloaded them online. And when running `DeepVideoSummExample` with the following example command as stated in the repo, I get an error right away:

`./build/DeepVideoSummExample -videoFile Sample_NEW.mp4 -videoSaveFile outdeep.avi -summaryModelSim 0 -simcover 0 -segmentType 0 -summaryAlgo 0 -featureLayer loss3/classifier -network_file Models/googlenet_places205/deploy_places205.protxt -trained_file Models/googlenet_places205/googlelet_places205_train_iter_2400000.caffemodel -mean_file Models/hybridCNN/hybridCNN_mean.binaryproto -label_file Models/googlenet_places205/categoryIndex_places205.csv -budget 30`

And error (a lot of outputs....but here is the end):

```
F0918 20:11:34.079298 17067 blob.cpp:496] Check failed: count_ == proto.data_size() (1 vs. 0)
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
```

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4xbkuyzcoqzc10w/log.txt?dl=0) are the extended errors.

What's the problem? How to fix it?